# Fetch Json response in AEM sightly

Tags: jquery, json, aem, sightly

I am working on a AEM component where my field data (drop down values, dynamic input values etc) is getting fetched from json file. This json is called from jquery ready function.

I am getting 404 error on my browser for this json response. I know AEM reserves the use of ".json" file, Is there a alternate way I can fetch these values ? 
the way my json is called as

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ <br>
DataAccessLayer.SetSomething("./data/myjsonFile.json");

});
```

Comment: What is the actual URL that jQuery is trying to load the JSON from? Could it be that the loaded path is relative to the page you put the component in and the JSON file is in same path but relative to component scripts?

Comment: what are you trying to do there ?

1. fetch data from AEM via ajax call ? 2. place an output of json file directly within the component ?
if it's the ajax call - then where do you have then actual call to server ? what is then final requests URL ?

Comment: @ub1k I am calling javascrit function within my aem html file. Now my js function has this this jquery call for json where I am trying to fetch this data within my AEM page

Comment: what's the request that comes through to AEM ? the full URL.

Comment: @Vlad yes loaded path is relative and json file is in the same path. I tried giving the absolute path  too as we provide in AEM but it really doesnt affect the error response.

Comment: what's the request that comes through to AEM ? the full URL. is it sth like: `http://localhost:4502/content/mytestapp/page/jcr:content/parsys/thecomponent/data/mysonFile.json`

Comment: I feel that your jsonfile is sth you keep statically within the component itself `/app/yourapp/components/thecomponent/data/myjsonFile.json/` whilst your requesting something within your `/content/yourapp/` section where this file is just not present

Comment: @ub1k AEM request comes as <br/> http://localhost:4502/content/mytestapp.html <br/> when I am trying to run this page I am not getting any error but page with no data loaded on the fields ( drop down, input etc) . <br/> When I am inspecting the element on my page I can see the javascript error showing 404 for json. I inspected it through network to check the further issue, where myJson.json file was giving error   <br/> Cannot serve request to /content/app/data/calculatorData.json in /apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp

Comment: @ub1k moved my json data file inside the component folder and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @ub1k Not able to fetch the same json in publish environment. Any idea why?

Comment: because of dispatcher filters or because of proper configuration of Default Get Servlet

Comment: @ub1k  I am not using dispatcher right now, All I did is installed the package on my publish environment. Though it is working on the localhost url  http://localhost:4503/content/myPage.html  but when I am trying to access it via my machine name or IP address, the json data is not fetching.

Comment: can you request anything with JSON extension? like: 
http://localhost:4503/content/myPage.json ?

Comment: @ub1k     http://localhost:4503/apps/myapp/components/data/mydata.json    giving 304 staus code while     http://mymachinename:4503/apps/myapp/components/data/mydata.json giving 404 status code

Comment: @ub1k Yes I am able to access json via  - localhost and machine name both

Comment: @ub1k Resolved, it was a login issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per discussion in comments

> I feel that your jsonfile is sth you keep statically within the
>   component itself
>   `/app/yourapp/components/thecomponent/data/myjsonFile.json` whilst
>   your requesting something within your `/content/yourapp` section where
>   this file is just not present

answer

> moved my json data file inside the component folder and it worked